# Fast alternative for String.split by whitespace

Tags: java, performance, strings

After profiling of one project I've found a bottleneck in the code, specifically the line:

```
String columns[] = line.split("\\s+");
```

I've tried to find a workaround, but all ready made solutions, such as `StringTokenizer` and `Scanner` seem to be less efficient (for example, look at [the answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12831515/1102014)). So I decided to write a custom function.

```
private List<String> fastSplitWS(final String text)
{
  final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

  if(text != null)
  {
    final int n = text.length();
    if(n > 0)
    {
      int index1 = 0;
      char x = 0;
      boolean y = false; // "preceding char is separator" flag
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        x = text.charAt(i);

        if(x == '\t' || x == ' ') // if((x >= 9 && x <= 13) || x == ' ')
        {
          if(!y)
          {
            String token = text.substring(index1, i);
            result.add(token);
          }
          index1 = i + 1;
          y = true;
        }
        else
        {
          y = false;
        }
      }

      if(index1 < n - 1)
      {
        result.add(text.substring(index1));
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

The problem is that the code performs even worse than `String.split()` although I don't see how to improve it. According to profiler, most problematic parts are:

- `self` (lines of the plain code in this method) - 58%
- `String.charAt` - 21%
- `String.subString` - 12%
- `ArrayList.add` - 7%

Could someone suggest how to optimize the `self` code?

Comment: What is the code you using to benchmark?

Comment: You may wish to consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001330/java-split-string-performances

Comment: @EricStein, this is a part of Android app, DDMS profiler was used.

Comment: `\s` covers more white space chars than just space and tab... If you only need these 2, an own implementation might be faster, otherwise don't compete with libraries :).

Comment: @Paebbels, yes, I did consider this point (see commented `if` with the full set of whitespace characters) and then chose tab and space because other variants are eliminated in this specific place. But I'm not sure that adding one more condition will slow down my code a lot, and if not - it will remain 2 times faster than `split("\\s+")`. So your remark about useless competition can be incorrect.

Comment: For instance Wikipedia lists more than 30 [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). Using an regular expression also involves translating the regexp into a state machine and compiling this SM into byte code. So yes if you need only `space` and `tab`, you'll be faster, but if you are going to be unicode compliant ...

Comment: @Paebbels, I can be wrong, but I consulted about '\s' regexp class with [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) and it is limited to the abovementioned subset.

Comment: @Paebbels, yes, you're right in the case of Android's `split`, because it uses ICU's [regexps](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), and they include unicode whitespaces as well. But the shortlist is ok for my purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Bug #1

You have an off-by-one error here:

> ```
>   if(index1 < n - 1)
>   {
>     result.add(text.substring(index1));
>   }
> ```

The consequence of this is that `"a b c"` will be split to `["a", "b"]`, poor `"c"` is left out.

#### Bug #2

I would expect the same output for these calls:

> ```
> fastSplitWS("");
> fastSplitWS("   ");
> ```

But that's not the case. The first returns an empty list, the second a list with a single empty string in it.
This behavior is also inconsistent with `String.split`.

This is caused by this:

> ```
> if(!y)
> ```

One way to fix:

```
if(!y && i > 0)
```

Another way is to initialize `y` to `true`.
(Notice that with this variable name,
it's hard to understand the logical meaning of this.)

#### Readability

[@TopinFrassi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40395/topinfrassi) was too kind.
I find this code extremely hard to read,
mostly due to the poor naming throughout.
The unconventional indenting and brace placement don't help.

#### Performance

It's worth nothing the trade-offs of using [`.charAt`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.charAt%28int%29) and [`.toCharArray`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.toCharArray%28%29).
Take a look at those links, of the implementations in OpenJDK 8:

- `toCharArray` does an `arraycopy`, using double the space
- `charAt` does a boundary check on the index parameter

Which one is more efficient? I've no idea...

#### Improvement ideas

The indentation levels can be reduced here:

> ```
>   if(text != null)
>   {
>     final int n = text.length();
>     if(n > 0)
>     {
> ```

The first one can be reduced using an early return:

```
if(text == null) return result;
final int n = text.length();
if(n > 0)
{
```

The second can be reduced by eliminating the `if(n > 0)` completely,
as the loop logic takes care of the `n == 0` case automatically.

#### Suggested implementation

Applying the above suggestions and bugfixes, the implementation becomes:

```
private List<String> fastSplitWS(final String text) {
    if (text == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("the text to split should not be null");
    }

    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    final int len = text.length();
    int tokenStart = 0;
    boolean prevCharIsSeparator = true;  // "preceding char is separator" flag

    char[] chars = text.toCharArray();

    for (int pos = 0; pos < len; ++pos) {
        char c = chars[pos];

        if (c == '\t' || c == ' ') {
            if (!prevCharIsSeparator) {
                result.add(text.substring(tokenStart, pos));
                prevCharIsSeparator = true;
            }
            tokenStart = pos + 1;
        } else {
            prevCharIsSeparator = false;
        }
    }

    if (tokenStart < len) {
        result.add(text.substring(tokenStart));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your indentation is on the limit of being hard to read! :p Usually there's more indentation between two nested things. Ex :

Your code :

```
if(true)
{
 if(true && 1==1)
 {
 }
}
```

Usually :

```
if(true)
{
    if(true && 1==1)
    {
    }
}
```

It is much easier to read this way! Also, Java conventions point that the bracket's style should be "egyptian" meaning :

```
if(...) {
}
```

instead of

```
if(...)
{
}
```

You could reduce the nesting (and hence enhance readability) by reversing the logic of your first `if`. Instead of :

```
if(text != null) {
}
```

You *should* write :

```
if(text == null) {
    return result;
}
```

This way there's less code in your `if`, and well, that's easier to read.

Another way to remove the `else` code block would be to introduce a variable that checks if the *current* character is a separator.

Same thing for `n > 0`. Although you could simply drop this condition. If `n==0`, then your `for` loop simply won't be executed and "voilà", you return `result`.

Look at this : `boolean y = false; // "preceding char is separator" flag`

If you have a comment explaining what your variable does, then your variable isn't well named. Why wouldn't you name your `boolean precedingCharIsSeparator`? Is it too long? I don't think so, plus it would mean the comment is now useless, you could remove it. Remember that long variable names aren't longer to compute! :p

The overall naming needs to be reviewed. It won't help for performance, but it will sure as hell help for readability, which is the second biggest concern of your code.

There's something you need to understand about profiling. The final result will **always** be 100%. The fact that your code takes 58% of the time isn't abnormal. It could be 58% of 1 millisecond or 58% of 10 minutes. If the bottleneck of your application is `split`, your application is probably fine. Otherwise you maybe need to check if you can replace your `split` by something else.

Here's the final code, with better named variables, less nesting and the usage of a `char[]` which I think will speed up a little bit your code. (But I have no proof of what I'm saying! :p)

```
private static List<String> fastSplitWS(final String text)
{
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(text == null) {
        return result;
    }

    final char[] characters = text.toCharArray();
    final int length = characters.length;

    int newWordIndex = 0;
    boolean precedingCharIsSeparator = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char current = characters[i];
        boolean currentCharIsSeparator = current == '\t' || current == ' ';

        if(currentCharIsSeparator && !precedingCharIsSeparator) {
            result.add(new String(characters, newWordIndex, i - newWordIndex + 1));
        } else if(precedingCharIsSeparator) {
            newWordIndex = i;
        }
        precedingCharIsSeparator = currentCharIsSeparator;
    }

    if(newWordIndex < length - 1) {
        result.add(new String(characters, newWordIndex, length - newWordIndex));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Finally, the method name isn't very good. I guess `WS` stands for `WhiteSpace`, well you should write it fully! `splitOnWhitespace` would be a better name.

Finally (again lol), you should wonder if you really want to return a `List<String>`? Usually `split` returns an array, I think it should be the same here.

Comment: A micro-optimization to consider is using `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList`. For my pseudo-random input set, that shaves a few percentage points off.

Comment: Another micro-optimisation that depends on the use case is to pre-size the ArrayList. The default size is 10, might be worthwhile to increase it.

Comment: @Erik Maybe yeah, but wouldn't this cause an overhead in the case where there's only say.. 2 elements in the list?

Comment: Well, the style was not the point of my question, but thank you anyway :p - partially I agree (e.g. about indentation and long naming convention) and partially not. As for performance, I'll test your code. The reason why I asked the question is because 58% is too much IMHO for such simple code instructions in comparison to `charAt`, `substring`, and `add`.

Comment: @TopinFrassi No, it just sizes the backing array bigger. It reserves more memory for the refs, nothing else. In essence, just moving the free pointer.

Comment: @Stan Well, `charAt`, `substring` and `add` **are** simple operations :)

Comment: @TopinFrassi, yes, but not simplier than incrementing integers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a short answer about the use of `ArrayList`. It is almost always a poor option, as it is pretty much an array with helper functions. If you have an `ArrayList` of 10000 integers, and then add another integer, `ArrayList` will (if its current array it's storing the values in is of size 10000) create a new array, move all the values of the old array in the new array, then add the integer to the end. Sounds inefficient? Certainly does.

My opinion is to use `LinkedList`. `LinkedList` is faster, because it works like this:

- Each value in the list is stored in a `Node`.
- Each `Node` points to the next `Node`.
- Adding something to the end is as simple as creating a new `Node` and linking it to the `Node` chain.
- Removing and inserting is as simple as changing some links around.

Worst-case time complexity comparison:

```
        LinkedList        ArrayList
Get:       O(n)              O(1)
Add:       O(n)              O(n)
Insert:    O(n)              O(n)
```

Best-case time complexity comparison:

```
        LinkedList        ArrayList
Get:       O(1)              O(1)
Add:       O(1)              O(1)
Insert:    O(1)              O(n) <- assuming not inserting at end of list
```

Yes, `LinkedList` is losing, but in this case, you don't use `get` often. On the other hand, memory is an issue for `ArrayList`:

```
        LinkedList        ArrayList
Get:       O(1)              O(1)
Add:       O(1)              O(n)
Insert:    O(1)              O(n)
```