# Creating an ArrayList of Maps

Tags: java, array, android

I am making an `ArrayList` that contains `Map` values. `itemData` is my `ArrayList` that contains `itemselected`, which is a map. Then, because I want to send this array to my PHP code, I am converting `itemData` into a `JSONArray`. Then parsing the array in my PHP script and inserting those individual values into a MySQL database.

```
private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> itemData = new ArrayList<>();
private Map<String, String> itemselected = new HashMap<>();
JSONArray itemSelectedJson = new JSONArray();

 private void selectedItems() {
        if(invEstSwitch.isChecked())
        {
            billType = textViewEstimate.getText().toString();
        }else{
            billType = textViewInvoice.getText().toString();
        }

        itemselected.put("custInfo",custSelected.toString());
        itemselected.put("invoiceNo", textViewInvNo.getText().toString());
        itemselected.put("barcode", barCode.getText().toString());
        itemselected.put("desc", itemDesc.getText().toString());
        itemselected.put("weight", weightLine.getText().toString());
        itemselected.put("rate", rateAmount.getText().toString());
        itemselected.put("makingAmt", makingAmount.getText().toString());
        itemselected.put("net_rate", netRate.getText().toString());
        itemselected.put("itemTotal", itemtotal.getText().toString());
        itemselected.put("vat", textViewVat.getText().toString());
        itemselected.put("sum_total", textViewSum.getText().toString());
        itemselected.put("bill_type", billType);
        itemselected.put("date", textViewCurrentDate.getText().toString());

        //Add the map to the Array
        itemData.add(index, itemselected);
        itemSelectedJson= new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(itemData));
        index++;
    }
```

The code is pretty straightforward, but I am interested in any possible improvement. I am sure there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just some convention points:

- The indentation is off in the first couple of lines. Is this due to copy-paste? I have to assume so, as the rest of your code seems fine.
- The following `if` statement:

  ```
  if(invEstSwitch.isChecked())
  {
      billType = textViewEstimate.getText().toString();
  }else{
      billType = textViewInvoice.getText().toString();
  }
  ```

  is inconsistent. You put a newline before the beginning brace at the `if`, and not at the `else`.

  It is also bad formatting. There should be a space both left and right of the `else`, and a space after `if`:

  ```
  if (invEstSwitch.isChecked()) {
      billType = textViewEstimate.getText().toString();
  } else {
      billType = textViewInvoice.getText().toString();
  }
  ```
- The `if` statement can be simplified into a ternary expression, as it is assigning the same thing (assuming `textViewEstimate` and `textViewInvoice` are the same type):

  ```
  billType = (invEstSwitch.isChecked() ? textViewEstimate : textViewInvoice)
          .getText().toString();
  ```
- Try not to use `ArrayList`. As I said in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111201/fast-alternative-for-string-split-by-whitespace/111363#111363):

  > It is almost always a poor option, as it is pretty much an array with
  >   helper functions. If you have an `ArrayList` of 10000 integers, and
  >   then add another integer, `ArrayList` will (if its current array it's
  >   storing the values in is of size 10000) create a new array, move all
  >   the values of the old array in the new array, then add the integer to
  >   the end. Sounds inefficient? Certainly does.
  >
  > My opinion is to use `LinkedList`. `LinkedList` is faster, because it
  >   works like this:
  >
  > - Each value in the list is stored in a `Node`.
  > - Each `Node` points to the next `Node`.
  > - Adding something to the end is as simple as creating a new `Node` and linking it to the `Node` chain.
  > - Removing and inserting is as simple as changing some links around. The problem would be to find that link.
  >
  > Worst-case time complexity comparison:
  >
  > ```
  >         LinkedList        ArrayList
  > Get:       O(n)              O(1)
  > Add:       O(n)              O(n)
  > Insert:    O(n)              O(n)
  > ```
  >
  > Best-case time complexity comparison:
  >
  > ```
  >         LinkedList        ArrayList
  > Get:       O(1)              O(1)
  > Add:       O(1)              O(1)
  > Insert:    O(1)              O(n) <- assuming not inserting at end of list
  > ```
  >
  > Yes, `LinkedList` is losing, but in this case, you don't use `get`
  >   often. On the other hand, memory is an issue for `ArrayList`:
  >
  > ```
  >         LinkedList        ArrayList
  > Get:       O(1)              O(1)
  > Add:       O(1)              O(n)
  > Insert:    O(1)              O(n)
  > ```
- Your method is fairly inefficient. You create a new `JSONArray` each time you call the method. Instead, use the given [`put()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#put(java.util.Map)) method (this also means you don't need an `ArrayList`):

  ```
  private Map<String, String> itemselected = new HashMap<>();
  JSONArray itemSelectedJson = new JSONArray();

  private void selectedItems() {
      billType = (invEstSwitch.isChecked() ? textViewEstimate : textViewInvoice)
              .getText().toString();

      itemselected.put("custInfo",custSelected.toString());
      itemselected.put("invoiceNo", textViewInvNo.getText().toString());
      itemselected.put("barcode", barCode.getText().toString());
      itemselected.put("desc", itemDesc.getText().toString());
      itemselected.put("weight", weightLine.getText().toString());
      itemselected.put("rate", rateAmount.getText().toString());
      itemselected.put("makingAmt", makingAmount.getText().toString());
      itemselected.put("net_rate", netRate.getText().toString());
      itemselected.put("itemTotal", itemtotal.getText().toString());
      itemselected.put("vat", textViewVat.getText().toString());
      itemselected.put("sum_total", textViewSum.getText().toString());
      itemselected.put("bill_type", billType);
      itemselected.put("date", textViewCurrentDate.getText().toString());

      // Add the map to the Array
      itemSelectedJson.put(itemselected);
      index++;
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks a lot can you help improve my ArrayList implementation as well.Thanks

Comment: @AndroidNewBee What `ArrayList` implementation?

Comment: instead of putting the data into an ArrayList and then making it a jsonArray. Can't I just put all the data directly into an jsonArray. Would that improve my app performance?